# How to prioritize SSH to work in the event of high CPU load

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora

I'm encountering a weird problem where a Fedora Linux VPS server reports 100% CPU, and effectively becomes unusable, but I don't know why because the high load prevents me from SSHing into it to see what's wrong.

How do I prioritize or configure SSH so that I'm still able to connect even if some process is consuming all other CPU?

Comment: I don't think this is really possible, why not attack the problem at it's source? Work out what's causing the cpu to max out and fix THAT problem.

Comment: Maybe because he can't SSH in to attack the problem.  Chicken meets egg.  :)

Comment: @RobbieMckennie, And how do you propose I do that?

Comment: It sounds like it is a little late to force ssh to have priority. If you have 'physical' access, you might be able to get in. You might be about to run `ssh user@host sudo reboot` to try to make it restart, with less overhead then getting a full shell.

Comment: @demure, I don't have physical access. I can reboot it, but that destroys any evidence as to what the problem was.

Comment: @Cerin `top -d 15 -b` will output a list of running processes, along with their respective cpu usage, every 15 seconds. Something like `top -d 15 -b > log &` will run in the background and append the list to the file "log" every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If this is for real a CPU / Load related problem you can (re)nice the sshd process on your server to give it a higher priority.
To make that persistent you can add the nice inside the sshd init script.

Answer (score 3):

Create a script which logs processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
top -b -c -n 1 -d 1 > /tmp/top-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

Setup a cron job which runs the script every minute:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Next time your system goes unresponsive, you'll have logging of what was doing it.

Comment: For additional points, write another cron job which clears out old logging every few days so you don't fill up your filesystem. (hint: `find` and `-mtime`)

Answer (score 2):

I was running the code that was hogging all the resources through Docker, so I just limited the amount of CPU that could be consumed by the container by starting it with

```
--cpus=7.5
```

Because I have 8 cores, this means I should always have half a core for processing SSH sessions into the actual server running the container (unless some other process takes up those resources too).

For good measure I also limited the container's memory usage with

```
--memory=4g
```

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu

Comment: What ensures the cores you do use aren't where sshd runs? Is sshd smart enough to use any available core?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind my saying, I think you're asking the wrong question.  You really want to find out what is using so may resources to the point of your not being able to log in.  I have come across this problem numerous times and the solution is to track what is going on the server constantly.  I came up with this solution which is as light as possible, reducing its chances of being stopped by a resource hog:

http://linuxtech.ie/wordpress/2012/09/05/finding-a-severe-resource-hog-on-your-server/

I hope that helps

Comment: This is true. Treating the symptom, not the cause. I've **NEVER** had to make changes to the priority of the SSH daemon on a production system. I think this lies more with the deficiencies of the VPS provider or another resource issue.